# How to fix the warning in ggplot2: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to make a PCA score plot using ggplot2, then convert the `ggplot` object into interactive plotly. The interactive plot will show the sample name if the cursor will hover on a point.

Below is my minimum example, and it works quite well. but I got the following warning:

> In ggplot2::geom_point(data = df_pcs, mapping = aes(x = PC1, y = PC2,  :
> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label

I tried to use `text` aesthetics, but then the sample names are now shown in the interactive plot.

How can I fix this warning?

Thanks.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#(1) example data
dat <-  iris[1:4]
Group <- iris$Species

#(2) perform PCA
df_pca <- prcomp(dat, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
df_pcs <- data.frame(df_pca$x, Group = Group)


#(3) plot
hull_group <- df_pcs %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Sample_Name = rownames(df_pcs)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Group) %>%
  dplyr::slice(chull(PC1, PC2))

p2 <- ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_polygon(data = hull_group, 
                        mapping = aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, fill = Group, group = Group), 
                        alpha = 0.2) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data = df_pcs, 
                      mapping = aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = Group, label = rownames(df_pcs)), 
                      size = 3) +
  ggplot2::theme_bw()

plotly::ggplotly(p2, tooltip = "label")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
#library(poorly)
#(1) example data
dat <-  iris[1:4]
Group <- iris$Species

#(2) perform PCA
df_pca <- prcomp(dat, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
df_pcs <- data.frame(df_pca$x, Group = Group)


#(3) plot
hull_group <- df_pcs %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Sample_Name = rownames(df_pcs)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Group) %>%
  dplyr::slice(chull(PC1, PC2))

p2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(df_pcs, aes(text = rownames(df_pcs))) +
  ggplot2::geom_polygon(data = hull_group, 
                        mapping = aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, fill = Group, group = Group), 
                        alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = Group), 
                      size = 3) +
  ggplot2::theme_bw()

plotly::ggplotly(p2, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I think the problem was that `text` and `label` are not known aesthetics for the point geometry.  If you put the `text` aesthetic in the call to `ggplot()`, then the warning goes away.